# Passing a match in regsub with & to a procedure (Tcl is being used)

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to go through a comma separated string and replace matches with more comma separated elements.

i.e 5-A,B after the regsub should give me 1-A,2-A,3-A,4-A,5-A,B

The following is not working for me as & is being passed as an actual & instead of the actual match:

```
regsub -all {\d+\-\w+} $string [myConvertProc &]
```

However not attempting to pass the & and using it directly works:

```
regsub -all o "Hello World" &&&
> Hellooo Wooorld
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong in attempting to pass the value & holds to *myConvertProc*

***Edit:*** I think my initial problem is the [myConvertProc &] is getting evaluated first, so I am actually passing '&' to the procedure.

How do I get around this within the regex realm? Is it possible?

***Edit 2:*** I've already solved it using a foreach on a split list, so I'm just looking to see if this is possible within a regsub. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your first edit: the problem is that each argument to `regsub` is fully evaluated before executing the command.

One solution is to insert a command substitution string into the string, and then use `subst` on it:

```
set string [regsub -all {\d+\-\w+} $string {[myConvertProc &]}]
# -> [myConvertProc 5-A],B
set string [subst $string]
# -> 1-A,2-A,3-A,4-A,5-A,B
```

This will only work if there is nothing else in `string` that is subject to substitution (but you can of course turn off variable and backslash substitution).

The `foreach` solution is much better. An alternative `foreach` solution is to iterate over the result of `regexp -indices -inline -all`, but iterating over the parts of a split list is preferable if it works.

**Update:**

A typical `foreach` solution goes like this:

```
set res {}
foreach elem [split $string ,] {
    if {[regexp -- {^\d+-\w+$} $elem]} {
        lappend res [myConvertProc $elem]
    } else {
        lappend res $elem
    }
}
join $res ,
```

That is, you collect a result list by looking at each element in the raw list. If the element matches your requirement, you convert it and add the result to the result list. If the element doesn't match, you just add it to the result list.

It can be simplified somewhat in Tcl 8.6:

```
join [lmap elem [split $string ,] {
    if {[regexp -- {^\d+-\w+$} $elem]} {
        myConvertProc $elem
    } else {
        set elem
    }
}] ,
```

Which is the same thing, but the `lmap` command handles the result list for you.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm)

Comment: Thanks for examples! I really liked the command substitution, wish I had thought of it myself :)
 What I had ended up doing using foreach before trying the regbsub was iterating through the split list, then _myConvertProc_ would return a list that i would regsub into the place of the current element I was at in the foreach.

Comment: @Gsavin: you don't need `regsub` at all if you use `foreach`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean! I do have a followup though. Could the regsub not be used in place of the if/else all together? Sorry about formatting if it didnt work out. (myConvertProc for the sake of the example returns the same element if it doesnt have the format #-elem) 
    foreach elem $splitList {
        regsub $elem $splitList [myConvertProc $elem] splitList
    }

Comment: @Gsavin: you certainly could do it that way, but it's not the best solution. One problem with it is that as `splitList` changes, one of the inserted conversion results could unexpectedly match one of the `elem` strings (try it with the list `5-A,4-A,B`). It's good practice to do the simplest thing that will work: using `regsub` has a lot of potential complications.

Comment: I tend to steer away from the simplest solution every now and then :)